# Error while setting new secret in azure key vault using Azure data factory web activity using Rest API set secret

Tags: azure-data-factory

My requirement is i have to get a set of refresh token and access token from Autodesk api and store it in azure key vault[Using 3 legged authentication where i get refresh and access token based on a code]. Since the refresh token and access tokens expires in 24 hours, i need to get a set of new tokens everyday and store it securely in azure key vault. We are using Azure data factory pipeline for this as per requirement.

For the very first time when the refresh and access token are received we are saving it to the vault manually and from next cycle we will read previous token from vault and call the Autodesk API and retrieve new tokens. All this is done using ADF  web activity .
Getting old tokens from key vault is working. But setting new tokens to the vault is failing

I am using Web activity in ADF which calls the rest Azure set secret API for storing the tokens to key vault.
https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecretname?api-version=7.3

While executing this pipeline i am getting following error

Error details
Error code
2108
Troubleshooting guide
Failure type
User configuration issue
Details
{"error":{"code":"BadParameter","message":"Property has invalid value\r\n"}}
Source
Pipeline
pl_renew_refreshtoken_web_to_kv

Not able to understand what is Badparameter and property has invalid value, not much information on the azure documentation.

i have also set  Access policy for the service principal for the ADF  resource

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved.
In the body of web activity, I had to give the value as a json object like `{"value":"secretvalue"}`. I was giving like `value=secretvalue` which was causing the issue.